# Is Bootstrap 3 a mixture between fixed and fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The grid component in Boostrap 3 has in its default configuration four aspects where only the extra small devices' column width is set to auto. The other three ones (small, medium & large) have fixed sizes.

So is Bootstrap now a a mixture of fixed and fluid approach?

If yes, can somebody explain the reasons behind that decision? I've always had the understanding that one should not mix them up.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3.x the grid component (the col-) in ALL breakpoints are set in percentages. The .container is set at a width using pixels (earlier versions had a max-width) *depending* on the breakpoint. There is a new class coming out called .container-fluid. You can mix fixed and fluid depending on the situation, but the columns are all fluid, the .container is not.

Comment: So it is a mixture after all or let's say it offers both approaches?
When will the .container-fluid class be released?

Comment: When 3.1.0 comes out, I think any day now. It's in the Repo and I'm using it with LESS but it's not on their site yet.

Comment: Yes it's a mixture. But I never use the pixels, I customized mine to all to percentage and em based because there are so many devices now.